# Socket.io with Express Application Generator

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've been digging for hours for an easy solution to this question and I can't find one. How can I get started with Socket.io after using Express's application generator. For example, if I create a new app with 
`express myapp` and `npm install --save socket.io` how do I use in in my index.jade file?

My index.jade file is plain HTML right now and looks as such

```
html.
<head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();

      socket.on('message', function(msg){
          console.log('you got a message');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="768" height="720"></canvas>
</body>
```

My `routes/index.js` file looks as such

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var io = require('socket.io')();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    io.emit('text', { for: 'everyone' });  
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Nothing happens when I go to my app's homepage though. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325154/5045925) SO answer but my app only fires the "A user connected" message. My `io.emit` never fires in my index.js file.

Comment: put `io.emit` inside `io.on( "connection")` callback

Comment: I don't want all of my socket.io logic inside my ```app.js``` file though, I need to be able to use ```emit``` from inside of my ```router.get``` function.

Comment: well, you have to make a socket connection first before emitting.  Your code emits first and then when render completes in browser it makes the connection.

Comment: Have you started your server? and attached the webSocket infrastructure to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the socket code outside the REST api and try this:

```
io.on( "connection", function( socket )
{
    console.log( "A user connected" );
    socket.emit('text', { for: 'everyone' });
});
```