# Use of Socket.io and express 4.3 with express-generator

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io with express 4 and express-generator, however I'm having an issue that the connection event from socket.io don't fires. I have the following settings for my project:

**./bin/www**

```
var load = require('express-load');

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
*/

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {});
load('sockets').into(io);
```

**socket/chat.js**

```
module.exports = function (io) {
   var sockets = io.sockets;

   sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
        console.log('A user had connected: ', client);
   });

   console.log('Sockets Events: ', sockets._events.connection);
};
```

The function of the event is properly logged to the conseole, but when I try to connect I don't receive the log from the event.

I already tried the solutions on this thread: [Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

But none solved my issue, thanks in advance.