# socket.io with express generator

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Before write this i tried the solution at [Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

The terminal show an error on `/routes/messages.js:12`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Here comes my files:

**/routes/messages.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('../controllers/messageController');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', controller.plain);

module.exports = function(io){
  var router = express.Router();

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('**********************************************************');
    console.log('mensaje desde socket.io en el archivo de rutas messages.js');
    console.log('**********************************************************');
  });
  return router;
};
```

**/bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('archiers:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);


/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);

// socket.io

var io = app.io;
io.attach(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**/app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// var for routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var projects = require('./routes/projects');
var messages = require('./routes/messages')(io);

var app = express();

// socket.io

var io = socket();
app.io = io;

io.on( "connection", function( socket )
{
    console.log( "A user connected" );
});

// para devolver estado por consola.
app.use(morgan('combined'));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
var Account = require('./models/accounts');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(multer({dest : "./userFiles/projectImage"}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'secretpass',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge : 3600000 } //1 Hour
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//Rutas express
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/user', users);
app.use('/project', projects);
app.use('/message', messages)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Marcos You don't have to anwser a question when you really want to leave a comment  to @Gilad. For your question, what happen if you remove the io.on('conection') from your app.js and you just have the io.on('connection') in your messages.js ?

Comment: I added var messages = require('./routes/messages')(io); as Gilad said, this solve the error, the next is to view a log message when someones connects to /message on the browser.

Comment: Okay! So try what I say, maybe the second io.on('connection') located in your app.js is overriding the first you set up in your messages.js file. Remove the piece of code io.on('connection', ...) from your app.js

Comment: nothing happened on terminal:
******************************************************************
aquí vendran los mensajes del socket.io desde messageController.js
******************************************************************
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2016:14:15:34 +0000] "GET /message HTTP/1.1" 500 2744 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
GET /message 500 165.845 ms - 2744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in app.js you have this code:

```
var messages = require('./routes/messages')(io);

var app = express();

// socket.io

var io = socket();
app.io = io;
```

You should initialize io variable before passing it to messages export function - like so:

```
var app = express();

// socket.io

var io = socket();
app.io = io;

var messages = require('./routes/messages')(io);
```