# Socket.IO sending message to server but won't send anything back to client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nitrousio

This has been driving me a little nuts over the past day, and after extensive research I still can't figure out.

I setup a Socket.io as shown in this question [Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

In my server code (`app.js`), I have the following:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("connected!");
  socket.emit('all',{});
});
```

Then in my client code (`index.jade`), I have the following:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('all', function (data) {
  console.log("here");
});
```

Unfortunately, when visiting index.

```
GET / 200 398.555 ms - 3957
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.913 ms - -
connected!
```

Basically, my server sees my client, but my client won't receive anything from my server?? Btw, if I try localhost in my io, I won't even see the "connected!" event.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
socket.on('all', function (data) {
  console.log("here");
});
```

Comment: You won't see the client's log in the terminal as I suspect you're doing. Try to see at your browser console.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Thank you SO MUCH. Ugh I can't believe I didn't see this. My sockets are working and my problem is solved :)

Comment: You're wellcome! Glad to help you! =)

Answer (score -1):

As said by Jose in the comments, I wasn't looking at the right place for my logs. The socket is working fine!

Comment: This should be a comment.