# private chat using socket.io in MEAN app

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, mean

i am trying to include chat features on my MEAN app, all i have completed till now is a medium where all connected users can communicate.not a separate group. i follow some of the tutorials but they do by trick like sending some key words in front of message(whistle as they say).
as far as i know every connected users are provided a seperate socket ID through which communication is carried but  i failed getting that id.

```
module.exports = function(socket){   
  //console.log(socket);    
  var users =[];

  socket.on('username',function(data){
    users.push({id:socket.id,username:data.message});
    socket.emit('username',users)
  })
  console.log('connected');  
    socket.on('typing',function(data){
      //socket.emit('typing',{message:"helo angular"});
      socket.broadcast.emit('typing',{message:data.message});
  });
```

It shows me socket is not defined, any one has better idea how to perform private message using socket.io and node.js
can anyone enlighten me about this.

Comment: where are you initialising `socket.io` server and creating new socket connection ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma on my main app.js my code goes here 
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket = require('./routes/socket.js');
server.listen(8000);
console.log('server listening on port:8000');
io.on('connection',socket);

Comment: can you share error stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

**Make all users join their own unique group.**

```
socket.join(socket.id);
```

**Then you can send a message to one user by doing this**

`io.sockets.in(whichever_user.id).emit('msg', "Hello there user lets have a private chat!");`

---

I would recommend using the Express framework of Node, and implenting Socket.io into it.
Here are some links telling you how to set up Express and Socket.io:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH5qsGnFkBM&lc=z135dbryaqbfitiee22pd33ouozhwft3q

---Youtube comment tells you how to set up express generator.

> Adrian Gąsiewicz:
>
> For those who want to have similar directory structure as Bucky:
>
> 1. Install Express generator "sudo npm install -g express-generator"
> 2. Go to directory where you want to create project and type "express myapp --ejs" 3. Select newly created directory --> "cd myapp"
> 3. Install all node_modules --> "npm install"
> 4. Run server --> "npm start"
> 5. Open browser and type "http://localhost:3000/" Have fun ;)

[Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

---This tells you how to set up socket in Node.js Express project.