# Socket.io client not receiving message event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

My project's skeleton is of express-generator thus used this workaround:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)

SERVER:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  io.emit('message', msg);
});
});
```

CLIENT:(src for socket included)

```
var  socket = io.connect('//localhost:5000');

 function op(){
  socket.emit('message', $('input[name=yolo]:checked', '#myForm').val());
 };

 socket.on('message', function(msg){
     console.log("oo");
     $("input[value=msg]").attr('disabled',true);
     alert($("input[value=msg]").val());
 });
```

FORM

```
form(action='' id="myForm")
///form inputs
input(type="submit" value="book" onclick="op()")
```

1. Connection is made on both sides verified.
2. Message is received by the server but it isn't emitting it for the client side socket.on('message'... to trigger.
3. Tested every step only the last socket.on('message'.. not triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was using `Firefox` and it's just not working with `Socket.io` shifted to `chrome` and everything is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  io.emit('message', msg);
});
});
```

to

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  socket.emit('message', msg);
});
});
```

Comment: It should be 'io' only , tried your suggestion not working.

Comment: If you want to emit it to all clients, use:
`io.sockets.emit('message', msg);`

Comment: Yeah which is equivalent to 'io.emit' .

Comment: I think he wants to emit to all clients including the sender of the message, so he is right to use io.emit instead of socket.emit (which will only work for the sender of the message). So this answer is wrong in this situation.