# How to use Socket.io combined with Express.JS (using Express application generator)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use Socket.io combined with Express.JS (using Express application generator).
I've found some aswers how to do this ([Using socket.io in Express 4 and express-generator's /bin/www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609991/using-socket-io-in-express-4-and-express-generators-bin-www)).
My problem is that i cannot make use of the sockets inside the routes folder.
I can use them in the app.js and bin/www.js files. When i call the route index.js it just keeps loading the webpage for a long time without giving any errors.
**bin/www.js**

```
...
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

var io     = app.io
io.attach( server );
...
```

**app.js**

```
...
// Express
var app = express();

// Socket.io
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;
var routes = require('./routes/index')(io);
...
```

**routes/index.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var app = require('express');
    var router = app.Router();

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('User connected');
    });

    return router;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer below help you? Any comments? If it helped you then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646) so other people who search for it could see that it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example on how to use Socket.io with Express that I made available on GitHub here:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io

The backend code is this:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.error('express connection');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'si.html'));
});
io.on('connection', s => {
  console.error('socket.io connection');
  for (var t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    setTimeout(() => s.emit('message', 'message from server'), 1000*t);
});
http.listen(3002, () => console.error('listening on http://localhost:3002/'));
console.error('socket.io example');
```

See https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/si.js

As you can see here, I am creating the express app with:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

Then I create an http server with that app with:

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

And finally I use that http server to create the Socket.io instance:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

After running:

```
http.listen(3002, () => console.error('listening on http://localhost:3002/'));
```

it all works together.

You can see the entire example on GitHub with both backend and frontend code that works. It currently uses Express 4.14.0 and socket.io 1.4.8.

Comment: If i understand your answer correctly we can combine socket,io events && http requests to the same node-express server?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still want to use socket.io and express http request. Easiest way is to create two seprate instance of http server listing to different ports. 1 for websockets and 2nd for api requests.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    path: '/'
});

// routes and io on connection

httpServer.listen(5000, () => {
   console.log("Websocket started at port ", 5000)
});

app.listen(3000, () =>{
   console.log("Http server listening at", 3000)
})
```