# what is the best way to use socket.io with expressjs app?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to write a real-time chat application with socket.io and because my server and app file are separate, I kind of have no clue that how should I structure it to use socket.io instance in other parts of my app.
This is my `app.js` file.

```
const express = require("express");
const pug = require("pug");
const app = express();

module.exports = app;
```

and this is my `server.js` file

```
const app = require("./app");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${process.env.DATABASE}`)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`connection failed: ${err}`);
  });
```

what is the best way to create an instance of socket.io and start it's connection for use in other parts of app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747828/how-to-use-socket-io-combined-with-express-js-using-express-application-generat?rq=1

Comment: There is no best way. They are mostly unrelated.

Comment: so not best way, just how can I use them together with this approach?

Comment: Dupe question covers both options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http with express app and then connect sockets through that http connection and you can listen and emit the topics inside the `io.on('connection')`

```
const app = require("./app");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${process.env.DATABASE}`)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('socket connected',socket);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`connection failed: ${err}`);
  });
```

I will prefer this second way:

**App.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const pug = require("pug");
const app = express();
module.exports = app;
```

**Server.js**

```
const app = require("./app");
const realtime = require("./realtime");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const server = require("http").Server(app);

mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${process.env.DATABASE}`)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
    require("./realtime.js")(server);

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`connection failed: ${err}`);
  });
```

**Realtime.js**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    const io = require("socket.io")(app);
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("Socket connected")
    })
};
```

Comment: with this approach how can I use io instance in other files for managing chats?