# Socket.io in express js : Router.use requires middleware function but got undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am trying to integrator socket.io in my express js application (Created by express generator).

[Here is the answer i've followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28755185/2804362)

But it didn't worked.

Added following in `bin/www`

```
app.io = require('socket.io')();
app.io.attach(server);
```

When i modify `app.use('/', index);` with  `app.use('/', require('./routes/index')(app.io))`; in app.js file i got the following error

*

> Router.use requires middleware function but got undefined

*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is how you can implement socket.io with express.**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//serve static files and index.html
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); });

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //logic handled in here
});

http.listen(7000,function(){ console.log('listening on port: 7000'); });
```

The above code has one route for handling the serving of index.html, but of course you can extend with additional routes the same way you would in any other app.

**Here is how you can have access to socket.io within a route in express generator.**

In www:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
module.exports = {io:io}
```

Within index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var io = require('../bin/www')
  console.log('I now have access to io', io)
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Note, the above example is purely showing you how to gain access to the io object within index.js.  There are many better ways to require socket.io and pass the io object around, but those decisions seem to be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Where can i add this ??

Comment: I want to use io object in  `routes/index.js` but as per yr code everything is do in `app.js` file

Comment: You can make these changes within project_root/bin/www.

Comment: But how do i use `io` in `index.js` ?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: Just added yr code to `www` no errors show but `io.on` not fired

Comment: If you do "module.exports = io" in www, you can do io = require('path_to_module_exports_file') in another file and have access to the io object.

Comment: whats this `path_to_module_exports_file` means?? s

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your exact situation.

Comment: Got it but there is another error `io.on('connection',function(obj){
       console.log('Client connected');
    });` throws  io.on is not a function

Comment: In module.exports I assigned the io object to an io key.  Just habit since many times you will want to export multiple variables.  Try io.io.on('connection'.....rest of your code, and it should work.

Comment: No errors one more question for firing `io.connection` is it necessary socket client library??

Comment: Yes, you need to include the socket.io javascript within your front-end as well else you will not be able to make a connection.

Comment: Thanks let me try it